# TStringList CustomSort Index2 value

Tags: sorting, delphi, tstringlist

I am using a `CustomSort` on a `TStringList` to order my strings from newest to oldest.

```
function dateSort(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
```

I noticed that that the starting value of `Index1` is `0` but the starting value of `Index2` is half the number of items in the `TStringList` rounded up (e.g `23` items in the list would mean `Index2` starts at `12`) - why is this?

Comment: The starting values depend on the [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) used, which you need not care about. Your job is only to implement the [comparison function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) to be used by the sorting algorithm. (In this case, the sorting algorithm is a form of [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), I believe.)

Comment: Why do you care? Are you just curious about how sorting works? Or do you have a problem with your program?

Comment: My program works fine - I was just curious about how this sorting works. I had a look online but I could not find any information.

Comment: Because TStringList.CustomSort uses a quicksort algorithm, not a bubble sort. You should look at the source to see what it does; one of the great things about Delphi is that you get almost all of the source for the VCL/FMX/RTL.

Comment: @Jsk: I encourage you to continue being curious! In this case, the three links I provided will give you all the answers you seek.